# Either of two SQL tables have a value

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have two tables, `task_list_sharee` and `task_list_assignee`.  They both have a reference to a `task_list` table.

There's also a `task` table that has a reference to the `task_list` table since a `task` always exists within a `task_list`.

Given a `task`, I want to find out if either `task_list_sharee` OR `task_list_assignee` have values.  Right now I'm doing it as two SQL statements, like so:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM task_list_assignee a 
INNER JOIN task_list l ON l.uid = a.task_list_uid
INNER JOIN task t ON t.task_list_uid = l.uid
WHERE t.uid = ?

SELECT count(*)
FROM task_list_sharee s 
INNER JOIN task_list l ON l.uid = s.task_list_uid
INNER JOIN task t ON t.task_list_uid = l.uid
WHERE t.uid = ?
```

and if either is non-zero I punt.  I'm thinking this has to be doable as just a single SQL statement but I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: the 2 queries are the exact same..what do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance of a full count on multiple joins (even more so for `LEFT JOIN`) can deteriorate quickly. While all you need is proof for the existence of a single row, there is no need for this. Use [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) - true to its name - to allow an optimal query plan:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   task t
   WHERE  t.uid = ?  -- provide uid here
   AND   (
      EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   task_list_assignee
         WHERE  task_list_uid = t.task_list_uid
         )
   OR EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   task_list_sharee
         WHERE  task_list_uid = t.task_list_uid
         )
      )
   );
```

Should be ***substantially*** faster than a full count.

I also *cut out the middleman*. Joining to `task_list` only establishes that the related row in `task_list` exists - which is a waste of time given that:

> a `task` always exists within a `task_list`.

Ideally implemented with FK constraints to enforce referential integrity. 
In the absence of actual table definitions my educated guess will have to do.

To make this *fast* for any table size, you need 3 btree (default) indexes on

```
task(uid, task_list_uid)
task_list_assignee(task_list_uid)
task_list_sharee(task_list_uid)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start with Task as your base table and do a series of left joins, you should be able to determine which tasks have values for both assignee and sharee with a [coalesce](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html):

```
select count(*)
from task as t
    left join
    task_list as l
    on t.task_list_uid = l.uid
    left join
    task_list_assignee as a
    on l.uid = a.task_list_uid
    left join
    task_list_sharee as s
    on l.uid = s.task_list_uid
where coalesce( a.task_list_uid, s.task_list_uid ) is not null
      and t.uid = ?
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/96186/7)